# NavigationLink in DisclosureGroup is not working when clicked

Tags: list, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to make a NavigationLink to "appleView()" swift file in a DisclosureGroup with the title "fruits".
But the NavigationLink is not working when clicked.
I don't know how to fix it.
I would appreciate it if anybody helped.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var fruitsExpanded: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            
            
            DisclosureGroup(
                isExpanded: $fruitsExpanded,
                content: {
                    List() {
                        
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: AppleView(),
                            label: {
                                Text("Apple")
                                
                            })
                        
                        Text("Banana")
                    }
                },
                label: { Text("Fruits") }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need NavigationView for that, so wrap Form into it.

Comment: Thank you Asperi. Your comment helped me a lot.

Comment: For me, I had put the disclosure group in a LazyVStack. Asperi pointed me in the right direction.